# How to Call/Display Foreach Loop after Login

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I had problem on calling page inside Foreach Loop.Although It is Okay before I click Login, but when I'd try to login,only the html tag where loaded and foreach loop cannot...       On my `HomeController` extends Controller

```
public function index()
{
    return view('pages.welcome');
}
```

on where I call `welcome` page. and inside of it which is foreach loop.

```
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
      @foreach ($posts as $post)
            <div class="post">
              <h3>{{ $post->title }}</h3>
              <p>{{ substr($post->body, 0,300) }}
              {{ strlen($post->body) > 300 ? "..." : " " }}</p>
        <a href="{{ url($post->slug)}}" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Read More...</a>
            </div>
        <hr>
      @endforeach
    </div>
 </div>
```

And I think the problem is my route:

`Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');`

Comment: you haven't passed `$posts` data into index method while returning view.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't passed the `$posts` variable to the view.

Change

```
public function index()
{
    return view('pages.welcome');
}
```

To something like this:

```
public function index()
{
    $posts = \App\Post::all(); //Assuming your model is called "Post" in the App namespace
    return view('pages.welcome', compact('posts'));
}
```

NOTE: [compact](http://php.net/manual/en/function.compact.php)('posts') is just a shortcut for ['posts'=>$posts]